# What's the best programming language for cryptography? (beginner)

Tags: encryption

For a beginner user, and someone with not a huge math background, what would be the best or easiest programming language to start doing cryptography in?

Comment: For academic purposes, python will probably do a good job with its native big-integer support, the bit-masking primitives, the wide availability, the REPL tools and the standard supported paradigms.

Comment: Are you a beginner to programming, or a beginner to cryptography? If you're a beginner to programming, you can't beat python for learning. If you're already a master of C or assembly, there's no reason not to use them. Either way, you'd probably want to hold off on writing anything to be used in production for a good long while, due to the pitfalls and intricacies of side channels, and how mundane bugs can become critical security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple

[Python](https://www.python.org) makes implementing certain types of algorithms easy without being insanely slow, namely those that use a few simple operations on BigIntegers ([RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), [DH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), etc).

Symmetric algorithms such as [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or [SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) implemented in Python will be slow.

For writing simple programs to cryptanalyze classic ciphers, Python is a pretty solid choice - normally they are weak enough to not require huge amounts of CPU time to crack.

### Fast

If you want the resultant code to be fast, you will need to run native code. Despite all of the pitfalls, [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) is the go-to language for speed (pun intended).

Keep in mind that there are [countless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL#Notable_vulnerabilities) things that [could go wrong](https://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/lazar-cryptobugs.pdf) with writing cryptography code, [*especially* in C](http://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/~drs/ctec1401/bugs.html).

### For Production

The above advice is recommended for *learning*. If you need production quality software, use a [pre-existing](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/) library to accomplish your needs, instead of writing your own from scratch. Unless you are already a [master of the language](https://cryptocoding.net/index.php/Coding_rules) and [CPU architecture](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176803/meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities?noredirect=1&lq=1), it's probably best to leave serious-business for-production code to people [who already know what they are doing](https://bearssl.org).

With crypto code, your learning experiences will be other peoples loss of private personal information. It is best not to subject your users information to needless exposure where possible.

### Java, Rust, Etc

I have never used any of the following languages, but they may be useful/applicable:

- [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) offers BigInteger arithmetic
- [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)) is supposed to be very safe

Comment: The advantage of the Java Crypto Architecture (JCA) is that it uses a relatively well documented, sensible API. It is plugable which means it can easily be expanded. It doesn't try to do too much such as encoding. So it acts as a good start for developing applications. Nowadays it even sports a REPL. But it remains a relatively verbose language with some tricky constructs when it comes to implementing your own algorithms. Python may indeed be better.

Comment: R is also good for cryptography as it is a language designed specifically for mathematical analysis. It's pretty slow though, so it's really only useful for studying.